# how to upload multiple image with thumbnail and select one of them before upload

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, image-uploading

I am working on quiz game where i need to upload multiple image with thumbnail before images upload but at the same time i must be able to select one image.Here purpose is i upload multiple image as option image and obviously one of the image is answer image between them.i need to store all the images URL and answer image URL in sepraet column of database.

i tried multiple image upload with thumbnail but how to select one image from them i don't know.please help thanks in advance.

i tried below code from `jsfiddel`

```
var inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("file");
inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change",previewImages,false);

function previewImages(){
    var fileList = this.files;

    var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

    for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
        var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
        $('#imagePreview').append('<img src="' + objectUrl + '" width="100" height="100"/>');
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
    }
}
```

And html is

```
<input id="file" type="file" name="file[]" multiple/>
<div id="imagePreview"></div>
```

here is the url http://jsfiddle.net/7s9krm2h/

Comment: ***"i need to upload multiple image with thumbnail before images upload"*** can you please clarify what you need?

Comment: i want to upload multiple images for some quiz question and after that i want to select one image from them as answer image.

Comment: You mean that you upload multiple images and after that you have to select one from the selected as an answer image!!..

Comment: yes but before form submit.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you can create a `hidden` field. When user clicks on an `img` store the index in the `hidden`. This field will sent to server with the form.

**Like this:**

```js
var inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("file");
inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change",previewImages,false);

function previewImages(){
  var fileList = this.files;
  var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){
    var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
    $('#imagePreview').append('<img src="' + objectUrl + '" />');
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
  }
}

$('#imagePreview').on('click', 'img', function() {
  var images = $('#imagePreview img').removeClass('selected'),
      img = $(this).addClass('selected');
  
  $('#answer').val(images.index(img));
});

$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($('form').serialize());
});
```

```css
img {
  padding:5px;
  border:3px solid silver;
}

img:hover, img.selected {
  border:3px solid green;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="file" type="file" name="file[]" multiple/>
  <input type="hidden" name="answer" id="answer" />
  <div id="imagePreview"></div>
  <button type="submit">Fake send the form</button>
</form>
```